# How do I center fic horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs on a webpage. One is floating left and one is floating right. I want them both to always be centered horizontally so that everything inside those divs is always in the middle of the page.

CSS:

```
#appInfoDiv{
float: right;
width: 60%;
background-color: black;
}
#appImgDiv{
float: left;
width: 40%;
}
```

I want both divs to always be in the center horizontally. I tried margin-top: 50% and margin-bottom: 50% but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you've used top and bottom margin... do you mean centered _vertically_ within the page or browser window?  You would use left and right to manage _horizontal_ position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this? `

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="inner">
    <div id="appInfoDiv">First Div</div>
    <div id="appImgDiv">Second Div</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Css :

```
.body {
display:block;
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid red;
}
.inner {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-60px;
top:50%;
margin-top:-25px;
width:120px;
height:50px;
background:green;
max-width:1400px;
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
padding: 4px 0;
}
#appInfoDiv{
float: left;
width: 60%;
height:40px;
background-color: black;
}
#appImgDiv{
float: left;
width: 40%;
height:40px;
background-color: red;
}
```

and fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/NcbHX/31/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `text-align:center`.  If you use it on the div that contains #appinfodiv and #appImgDiv, you should be able to center the divs without having to float them.

Also instead of floating the containers try

```
display:inline-block
vertical-align:top;
```

You might need to reduce the widths slightly to keep them on the same line.